STM32L432 sleep mode and wake up through RTC
I am developing a application for a battery-based 4G gateway so most of the time I want my microcontroller in sleep mode. I am using Standby mode as I require least power consumption. The requirement I need is I want to wake microcontroller at specific times like 6:00 AM and every 6 hours from that. Initially 6:00 AM time will be set and once alarm is raised, interrupt comes next alarm will be configured and again we go in sleep mode. Below is my configuration for RTC and alarm. The interrupt works as required when I don't call Enter_Standby_Mode function. But when I call Enter_Standby_Mode and controller goes in sleep, it won't come out of Sleep when RTC time matches ALARM A time. Basically its interrupt is not getting generated.
/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void Enter_Standby_Mode(void)
{

    // Clear all wake-up flags
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);

    // Clear RTC Alarm A flag
    __HAL_RTC_ALARM_CLEAR_FLAG(&hrtc, RTC_FLAG_ALRAF);

    // Suspend SysTick to reduce power consumption
    HAL_SuspendTick();

    // Enter Standby mode
    HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode();

}

void HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc)
{
  // Once the MCU wakes up, SysTick should be resumed
  HAL_ResumeTick();
  HAL_RTC_GetAlarm(hrtc,&sAlarm,RTC_ALARM_A,FORMAT_BIN);
  HAL_RTC_GetTime(hrtc,&sTime,FORMAT_BIN);
  HAL_RTC_GetDate(hrtc,&sDate,FORMAT_BIN);
  /*if(sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds>59)
  {
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds=0;
  }
  else
  {
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds=sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds+1;
  }
  while(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(hrtc, &sAlarm, FORMAT_BIN)!=HAL_OK){}*/
  // Once the MCU wakes up, SysTick should be resumed (re-enabled)
  //HAL_ResumeTick();
  LL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LED_Pin);
  PwrDwnFlag = 1;
}
/**
  * @brief RTC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */



  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */

  /** Initialize RTC Only
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /* USER CODE END Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /** Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date
  */
  sTime.Hours = 8;
  sTime.Minutes = 52;
  sTime.Seconds = 0;
  sTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sDate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_THURSDAY;
  sDate.Month = RTC_MONTH_SEPTEMBER;
  sDate.Date = 19;
  sDate.Year = 24;

  if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Enable the Alarm A
  */
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Hours = 8;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes = 53;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  sAlarm.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
  sAlarm.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_ALL;
  sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_DATE;
  sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDay = 1;
  sAlarm.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &sAlarm, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */

}


Welcome to EE.SE. Please [edit] your question, select the block of code and press the { } button. This will preserve indentation and apply syntax highlighting. Use 2 x  for paragraph breaks in your main text. Preview before posting.

It might not be the only problem, but you're missing the interrupt enable. It should be something like this:
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(RTC_Alarm_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(RTC_Alarm_IRQn);

The easiest way, if you're using STM32CubeMX, is to set it up through the 'NVIC settings' tab of the RTC settings.
